# How to call this.props from children class?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

So I make a gallery for my app that allows user to get images from their social media account. I use Redux for my app..and I already save facebook ID and TOKEN on my app store when the user login. I have no problem when I called **this.props.fbLoginData.TOKEN** from parent class.. however I always get

> undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.props.fbLoginData.TOKEN')

when I called this.props from my children class.

here is my Gallery(Parent) class:

```
_renderScene = ({ route }) => {
switch (route.key) {
case '1':
  return <View style={styles.page} />;
case '2':
  return <View style={styles.page} />;
case '3':
  return <FBPhotos />;
default:
  return null;
}
};

render() {
return (
  <TabViewAnimated
    style={[ styles.container, this.props.style ]}
    navigationState={this.state}
    renderScene={this._renderScene}
    renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
    onRequestChangeTab={this._handleChangeTab}
    initialLayout={initialLayout}
  />
);
```

}
}

and here is my fbPhotos class

```
componentWillMount(){
//this._facebookPhotoIDs();
fbToken = this.props.fbLoginData.TOKEN;
}

render(){
return (
 prop to style the items.
  <ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={this._renderRow}
  />
);
}
```

I've tried to bind this.props.fbLoginData.TOKEN but it will become empty.
How can I get fbLoginData state from fbPhotos class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `renderScene` method :

```
_renderScene = ({ route }) => {
  switch (route.key) {
    case '1':
      return <View style={styles.page} />;
    case '2':
      return <View style={styles.page} />;
    case '3':
      return <FBPhotos fbLoginData={this.props.fbLoginData} />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```